# Apple Pay error: Add Merchant ID to your App ID

Tags: ios, xcode, applepay

I've followed every step in setting up the Apple Pay certificate and my Merchant ID is set up and added to the App ID on my Apple Developer Account, but Xcode is still showing me an error that i need to "Add Merchant ID to App ID". I think my screenshot below clearly demonstrates that I have done so.

I only have one merchant ID so it's not that I'm pointing to the wrong ID. Can anyone guess what I may be missing or maybe I missed a step between downloading and authenticating my certificate?

[image: Screenshot of merchant id as it appears in Xcode]

Screenshot of App ID on my Apple Developer Account:

[image: Screenshot of enabled Merchant iD]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't know why it took so long to display this instruction underneath "Add Merchant IDs to your App ID". If you're patient enough, it will say "The operation requires a bundle identifier". At this point, you go to your project's Build Settings > Product Bundle Identifier, then input your app's bundle identifier, i.e., com.your.app.name

Comment: This fixed it, however I had `Bundle Identifier` correctly set in `General` > `Bundle Identifier`.  Why did this value not get propagated to `Build Settings` > `Product Bundle Identifier`?

Comment: Even after adding the bundle identifier I am still getting the error icon. What could I be missing? The error help text  'The operation requires a bundle identifier' has disappeared though.